# Django rest-framework filter models by the name of other models connected with foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

```
class Genre(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=255)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
class BlogText(models.Model):
    mytext = models.TextField(null=True)
    genre = models.ForeignKey(Genre, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
```

Each BlogText has Genre.

Now I can filter BlogText by `contains`

```
mytext = filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='contains')
```

then I want to filter `BlogText` models by `blogtext.genre.name`

I googled around but not found the reference other than CharFilter Contains. (even can't find IntFilter... I try to filter genre id directly....)

How can I make it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify [**`field_name`**](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/ref/filters.html#field-name)

```
genre = filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='contains', field_name='genre__name')
```

Comment: Thank you very much it's very simple and clear for me.